# R regular expression (near words)

Tags: regex, r

I was wondering how to select *words near each other* using regular expressions.
For example, I would like to select the digits and the word miles from the following phrases:

```
"140,000 mostly freeway miles" 
"173k commuter miles. "       
"154K(all highway) miles
```

I don't know how to fill in for the optional words in the middle:

```
[0-9]+ ???? miles
```

*near could be defined as 1-3 words apart. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What is "near"? Do you want to restrict the amount of characters or words between them? Or could they be arbitrarily far apart?

Comment: near could be 1-3 words apart

Comment: What language are you using for your regex? ...and why do you need to select the word "miles" when you know it will always be there?

Comment: @Lorax R **is** a language ;)

Comment: @m.buettner - doh! My mistake, I missed that. That'll teach me not to skim the question title so quickly next time :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer in `R`.  The other answers could work with some modification.  Mostly, they need to have "double escapes" and you will have to use the paired functions `regexpr` and `regmatches`.

```
x=c("140,000 mostly freeway miles" ,"173k commuter miles. " ,"154K(all highway) miles")


gsub('([[:digit:][:punct:]k]+).*(miles).*', 
     '\\1 \\2', 
     x,
     ignore.case=TRUE)

# [1] "140,000 miles" "173k miles"    "154 miles"
```

This says group numbers punctuation or a k in group 1.  Follow this by anything.  Then this is followed by group 2 which is the word miles, followed by anything else.

You could also use the "normal" regex syntax:

```
gsub('([0-9,k]+).*(miles).*', 
     '\\1 \\2', 
     x,
     ignore.case=TRUE)
```

However, I would clean up the data first then do some simpler matching! (e.g. `tolower` and remove punctuation).

Comment: This is missing out on the point that there have to be 1 to 3 words in  between. Feel free to copy my regex and make it work for R, I'll delete my answer then.

Comment: I'll stick with my note at the bottom of my post.  If `miles` shouldn't be included when its > 3 words away the regex is getting much too complicated!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of unanswered questions regarding the problem domain.  That aside, let's use the following data containing the provided sample data in the question for positive matches and some additional sample data for negative matches (I'm using `R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)`):

```
x <- c("140,000 mostly freeway miles", "173k commuter miles. ", "154K(all highway) miles", "1,24 almost but not mostly freeway miles", "1,2,3,4K MILES")
```

`1,2,3,4K MILES` is added as a negative match because the question defines near as `1-3 words apart` and this has zero "near words".

If we use the following ...

```
sub('[\\d,]+k?\\s+(([^\\s]+\\s+){1,3})miles', '\\1', x, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
```

... we get:

```
[1] "mostly freeway "
[2] "commuter . "
[3] "154K(all highway) miles"
[4] "1,24 almost but not mostly freeway miles"
[5] "1,2,3,4K MILES"
```

Probably not the result you want.  Because the data is not normalized, you would have to use a regular expression pattern that would get very complicated.  As [Justin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/906490/justin) suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13501366/649852), `clean up the data first then do some simpler matching`.

You could normalize the data some as follows:

```
y <- gsub('\\pP+', ' ', x, perl = TRUE)
y <- gsub('\\s+', ' ', y, perl = TRUE)
y <- gsub('^\\s+|\\s+$', '', y, perl = TRUE)
y <- gsub('(\\d)\\s(?=\\d)', '\\1\\2', y, perl = TRUE)
```

Please see the references below for more information.  This is basically removing punctuations and making sure words are separated by a single space.  This will leave you with `y` of:

```
[1] "140000 mostly freeway miles"
[2] "173k commuter miles"
[3] "154K all highway miles"
[4] "124 almost but not mostly freeway miles"
[5] "1234K MILES"
```

Now remove lines that don't match what you're looking for:

```
y <- sub('^(?!\\d+k?\\s((?!miles)[^\\s]+\\s){1,3}miles).*$', '', y, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
y
[1] "140000 mostly freeway miles" "173k commuter miles"
[3] "154K all highway miles"      ""
[5] ""
```

Finally, get the "near words":

```
y <- sub('^\\d+k?\\s((?!miles)[^\\s]+(\\s(?!miles)[^\\s]+){0,2})\\smiles', '\\1', y, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
y
[1] "mostly freeway" "commuter"       "all highway"    ""
[5] ""
```

There are probably simpler ways to normalize the data, but this gives you some regular expression examples to play around with.

For further information, see:

- The [R grep](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) command.
- The excellent [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) web site.
- The [`pcrepattern` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pcrepattern) for more information on Perl regular expression patterns.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `\d+([.,]\d+)?(?=.*?miles)`

Comment: How would you write that in `R`?

Comment: @Justin I guess if you use Perl-like regexes it should work right away.

Comment: The first paren is in the wrong place. With `gsub("\\d+([.,]\\d+)?(?=.*?miles)", "\\1 \\2", x, perl=TRUE)`, gives `",000  mostly freeway miles" " k commuter miles. " `. You do need to doubly escape backslashes in regex patterns for R.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a bit vague, but let's say we define everything as a "word" that is separated by spaces. So if there may be 1-3 words, there need to be 2-4 spaces (in fact I'll make the first one optional, seeing your last example) between the number and `miles`:

```
\d[\d,.]*k?\s*(\S+\s+){1,3}miles
```

Note that you should make this regex case-insensitive, to match both `k` and `K`.

Also note, that the number part could certainly be improved. This one will just take the first digit and  then include as many digits, commas and periods as possible, whether that makes a valid number format or not.